# What is the physical meaning of potential energy in a band diagram of a semiconductor?

Tags: energy, potential-energy, semiconductor-physics

According to this slide (from [this website](http://transport.ece.illinois.edu/ECE340F14-Lectures/ECE340Lecture13-OpticalAbsorption-Dist.pdf)), the potential energy of an electron in a semiconductor is defined by the difference between the Energy level of the conduction band and the fermi level.
But what is the physical meaning? (e.g. I understand that a higher object has more energy than a object closer to the ground).
And why is the potential energy not defined as the difference between the energy level of the electron and the fermi level?
[image]

Comment: "why is the potential energy not defined as the difference between **the energy level of the electron** and the fermi level" It is the same thing. The *energy level of the conduction band* is just a way to talk about the *energy the electrons in the conduction band may attain*. So this *is* the difference between electron energy level and fermi level.

Comment: We also cannot really talk about discrete energy levels because they are so closely packed in a semiconductor and merged into the conduction band

Comment: @Steeven, so can't electrons have a higher energy than the (fixed) energy level of the conduction band?